# jwplayer does not show player again after closing modal window

Tags: jquery, overlay, jwplayer

I have build a test page with an unordered list of images, that if clicked open a jwplayer with the respective video in an overlay/modal. When any of the images is first clicked everything works fine. The correct video is opened in the lightbox. However when the overlay is closed and we click on another image the overlay opens blank except for the closing button.

I have looked at many posts on the topic and still have no idea what the error is. I would really appreciate if someone can take a look and tell me what the issue is.

Here is my JS code:

```
//sets up the video player 

function setupVideoPlayer(s){ 

    var jwp = jwplayer('target').setup({ 
        file: s.videoLink, 
        title: s.videoTitle, 
        displaytitle: 'false', 
        width: '60%', 
        controls: 'true', 
        aspectratio: '16:9', 
        autostart: 'false', 
        stretching: 'fill' }); 

    var quality = jwplayer('target').setCurrentQuality(5); 
}

//creates the overlay, player and button

var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>'); 
var $player = $('<div id="target" class="jwp"></div>');
var $button = $('<a class="closeOverlay fa fa-times-circle"></a>');

//adds the overlay to the page 

$('body').append($overlay);

//adds player to the overlay 

$overlay.append($player);

//captures the click even on a video link 

$('#videoList a').click(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    var triggerLink = $(this).attr('href');

    //call the player everytime a videolink is clicked 

setupVideoPlayer({ 
        videoLink : triggerLink, 
        videoTitle : 'Keone & Mariel Madrid :: "Cups (When I\'m Gone)" by Anna Kendrick :: Urban Dance Camp' 
    }); 

    //remove old content from overlay

    $overlay.empty(); 
    //adds player and button to the overlay 
    $overlay.append($player);
    $overlay.prepend($button);
    //show the overlay 
    $overlay.show();

});

//closes overlay

$('body').on( 'click', 'a.closeOverlay', function() { $overlay.hide(); });
```

The html code is not that spectacular but just in case:

```
<body>
 <div id="page-container">
    <div id="content-container" class="group">
        <section id="main">
            <h1>Playback Time!</h1>
            <p>this is a simple test page to demonstrate a sidebar video playing in overlay mode</p>
        </section>
        <section id="sidebar">
            <p class="sectionTitle">Videos</p>
            <!-- MODAL TRIGGERS -->
        <ul id="videoList">
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLRPH3nFf8w">
              <img src="http://i1381.photobucket.com/albums/ah236/mxquel/92419208-c7b4-4591-a3bd-95ea9b732924_zps473abb42.png" alt="Thumbnail of a Video" />
            </a>
            <p>description or title of the first video</p>      
          </li> 
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cmSbXsFE3l8">
              <img src="http://i1381.photobucket.com/albums/ah236/mxquel/92419208-c7b4-4591-a3bd-95ea9b732924_zps473abb42.png" alt="Thumbnail of a Video" />
            </a>
            <p>description or title of the second video</p>     
          </li>
        </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: here it is [link](http://codepen.io/mxquel/full/b8fd598e549f41e30f959b3a0a80cac6/)

Comment: This is an issue with using YouTube content in 6.9. The player can't be set up again. This is fixed for 6.10, due out later this month. If Flash is set as Primary, this will be fixed, though.

Comment: ah thanks. I was going nuts trying to figure out what caused it. is it fine if I pull in the video another way?

Comment: Np. Yeah, it will be fine if the videos are not from YouTube. When 6.10 is released, YouTube will work again in this fashion.